# Units in the multipole expansion

Tags: electrostatics, dimensional-analysis, si-units, multipole-expansion

In the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Expansion_in_Cartesian_coordinates) the expression for the multipole expansion gives the dipole term as

$$V(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_{0}}\frac{∑P_{\alpha}r_{\alpha}}{r^{3}}$$

where the dipole is given by $P_{\alpha}=∑q_{i}r_{i\alpha}$. The units don't seem to cancel out. Wouldn't you need to multiply the dipole of one object by the dipole of another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you're looking at just gives the electrostatic potential generated by one dipole. The $r^3$ on the bottom cancels with 2 powers of $r$ on top leaving $\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$ which, just like the potential from a point charge, is in units of $\frac{J}{C}$.